# How to generate Dynamic lines around the circle in android

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I want to create dynamic lines around a circle which is glob picture.The size of the lines depends upon the total Numbers of rounds if total number of rounds are 10 then 10 lines are fit to the glob.

I tried below code in for loop dynamically lines are create but they are not in round shape. Please Help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Here is the Image in which you can see red. yellow and green line around the moon:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
int Stages = 10;
int circleCircumfarence = 785;
int spaceBetweenLine = 10;
int allspacesSize = 785 - (spaceBetweenLine * Stages);
int onelinesize = allspacesSize / 10; //250 is the width of circle
int x1 = (int) imgCatfill.getWidth() / 2;//image of globe 
int y1 = 10;
int x2 = (int) x1 + onelinesize;
int y2 = x2 / 10;
int curveRadius = 5;
int midX = x1 + ((x2 - x1) / 2);
int midY = y1 + ((y2 - y1) / 2);
float xDiff = midX - x1;
float yDiff = midY - y1;
double angle = (Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * (180 / Math.PI)) - 45;
double angleRadians = Math.toRadians(angle);
float pointX = (float) (midX + curveRadius * Math.cos(angleRadians));
float pointY = (float) (midY + curveRadius * Math.sin(angleRadians));
path.moveTo(x1, y1);
path.cubicTo(x1, y1, pointX, pointY, x2, y2);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```